# Why are shiny apps always getting immediately grayed out from RStudio behind `https://`?

Tags: r, https, shiny, rstudio, rstudio-server

Every time I try to run a shiny app from RStudio Server 1.2 it gets immediately grayed out. This does not happen when deployed on the Shiny Server-apps work fine there. Both are behind `https://` links. I tried running the same app from an `http://` link and the app ran normally. What is causing this?

Steps to reproduce:

1. start a new Shiny app project File > New Project > Shiny Web App
2. click "Run App" with the old faithful app

[image: grayed out shiny]

Here is what the javascript console shows:

[image: grayed out shiny js console]

A coworker is also using the same instance of RStudio to run their shiny apps and their apps are not being grayed out by default. It appears localized to my account. We are sharing the same set of installed R packages and neither of us have anything in our `.Rprofile` and `.Renviron`. Why could this be?

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
```

We are both running with `shiny_1.2.0`.

Comment: Grayed out usually means an error has occured. What does it show in the RStudio Window? Try using `rm(list=ls())` to remove any cache.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I started from a fresh R session. I think the problem is related to `https://` authentication on my RStudio Server. When I tried from `http://` the app ran with no issues.

Comment: It could be this https://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#specifying-protocols

Comment: The weird thing is that apps deployed with Shiny Server work great over `https://`. It's only the `Run App` based Shiny instances that don't work.

Comment: Do you use HTTPS via RStudio Server Pro or via a reverse proxy? If the latter: Which proxy do you use? How is it configured?

Comment: @RalfStubner: Yes. That was the problem. Modifying the Apache configuration resolved the issue. https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552326-Running-RStudio-Server-with-a-Proxy

Answer (score 0):

the root cause is your proxy. I use nginx as revert proxy, some config in proxy make my rstudio work. My config bellow

```
    location ~* /websocket/ {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        error_page 401 = @error401;
        auth_request_set $user $upstream_http_x_forwarded_user;
        auth_request_set $auth_status $upstream_status;

        proxy_read_timeout    300;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300;
        proxy_redirect        off;
        proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Ssl   on;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass http://your_proxy_upstream_or_ip;

    }
```